# USB AutoRun Dialog: Open a webpage option not shown in dialog

Tags: usb, autorun

I am attempting to make our webpage open when someone plugs in our USB device.

**My Problem:** When we plug in the USB device the autorun dialog appears but there is never an option to open/run the webpage we have specified. See below pic of the dialog we see. Isn't there meant to be an option that says something like "Open in Internet Explorer" or etc.?

[image]

What we are hoping to achieve is to have another option below 'Use this drive for backup' that says something like *'Open in Web Browser'* or something that will ultimately open our webpage when the users decides to.

Heres our code that is inside the file autorun.inf which is placed on the USB device:

```
[autorun]
shellexecute=http://exds-test.epicservices.com.au/V10InstallationInfo.aspx
action=Open Website
label=EXDS USB Drive
```

Answer (score 5):

Windows 7 doesn't support autorun for usb drives. Maybe this is your issue?

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/e7/archive/2009/04/27/improvements-to-autoplay.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/e7/improvements-to-autoplay)

Answer (score 1):

this Autoplay dialog is what windows shows after having a look at the USB drive's contents and it is also base on the applications you have installed on your windows for example if you have images in your flash drive and you have installed Picasa on your PC then your windows would show up another choice in the dialog for importing the images from usb drive to picasa...
but it would not run anything from the flash drive (it's a big security hole and it was fixed after windows xp).
* even if you might be able to make some changes on your windows to open up that website when the drive is plugged in, it would only work on your own PC not anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the commercial [Zentimo](http://zentimo.com/) management software for USB & eSATA devices ($29.9), which
gives more control over external drives :

[image]